# Cloud Functions: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I have this function written

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { setDoc, doc } = require("firebase/firestore");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functi
exports.idiot = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    // // Add a new document with a generated id
    const moment = require('moment')
    console.log("testtesttest 603")
    console.log(db.collection)
    const Questions = 
    {
        Questions: {
            QoD: "test",
            Upvotes: 0,
        }
    }
    const Comments = 
    {
        Comments: {
            Body: "hello",
            Replies: [],
            Upvotes: 0
        }
    }

    await setDoc(doc(db, "Questions", moment().format('MMM Do YYYY')), Questions);
    await setDoc(doc(db, "Comments", moment().format('MMM Do YYYY')), Comments);
});
```

And suddenly I am getting this error:

```
2022-09-28T00:59:00.846793Z ? idiot: FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
2022-09-28T00:59:00.848764071Z D idiot: Function execution took 9 ms. Finished with status: error
```

But it was writing to the document before.

Is there any reason why this error would pop up when the script was working before?

Comment: How id `db` initialized? From the error message it looks like, however you initialize it, it is not a `CollectionReference`, a `DocumentReference` or `FirebaseFirestore`, which are the types the API supports

Comment: const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

Comment: Not only can we not see how you create `db`, we also can't see any calls to `collection()` here (as the error message is complaining about.  Please **edit the question** to be more clear about the code that has a problem.  It might be helpful to read about how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're importing two different SDKs here:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { setDoc, doc } = require("firebase/firestore");
```

That first line imports the Firebase Admin SDK, which is designed to be used in trusted environments such as Cloud Functions.

The second line imports two functions from the client-side JavaScript SDK, which is made for use in regular applications.

While both SDKs have largely the same API, the two are not binary compatible. So the `db` variable points to a `Firestore` object the Admin SDK, while your `doc` function is expecting a `Firestore` object from the client-side JavaScript SDK.

To only use the Admin SDK:

```
const questionRef = db.doc("Questions", moment().format('MMM Do YYYY'));
await questionRef.set(Questions);
```

And then the equivalent for the comments.

In the documentation, you'll want to look for the `v8` code samples for this syntax, like here in the documentation on [writing to a document reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8).